# Calling a controller's action without a named route in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3, is there a way to link to a controller's action using ajax without having a named route?

I tried `<%= link_to 'Reload', '#', url_for(:action => :reload, :id => @user.id), :remote => true, :method => 'post' %>`

but it returns with the error `No route matches {:controller=>"users", :id=>2, :action=>"reload"}`

My main concern is that I don't want the action to be called by someone typing in a route in the address bar. Is there another way to go about this?

Thanks!

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your `User` resource is in your `routes.rb` file then you need to add a route to the 7 restful actions.

```
  resources :user, :member => {:reload => :get}
```

That will give you the route to work with

```
   <%= link_to "Reload", user_reload_path(current_user)%>
```

and that should work for reloading your user object

```
 rake routes
```

that will show you all your routes you can work with